# Hide all visible Metro Dialogs before showing another one

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, mahapps.metro

I'm using [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com) on my WPF project, and I am building a class to help me showing [Dialogs](http://mahapps.com/controls/dialogs.html). **I would like to know if there's a way of closing all visible dialogs before showing up another one.**

Sometimes, when I show a `ProgressDialog` and then a `MessageDialog` the ProgressDialog isn't correctly closed, and stays in the background, so when I close the MessageDialog, it stays there freezing the UI.

[image: GIF to ilustrate]

Here's how I'm currently trying to hide all Dialogs:

```
public static async void HideVisibleDialogs(MetroWindow parent)
{
    BaseMetroDialog dialogBeingShow = await parent.GetCurrentDialogAsync<BaseMetroDialog>();

    while (dialogBeingShow != null)
    {
        await parent.HideMetroDialogAsync(dialogBeingShow);
        dialogBeingShow = await parent.GetCurrentDialogAsync<BaseMetroDialog>();
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
public static MessageDialogResult ShowMessage(String title, String message, MetroWindow parent, Int32 timeout, MessageDialogStyle style, MetroDialogSettings settings, MessageDialogResult defaultResult)
{
    AutoResetEvent arEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        HideVisibleDialogs(parent);
        arEvent.Set();
    });

    arEvent.WaitOne();

    [Rest of method]
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

**@EDIT**

Apparently, the problem seems to be solved, thanks to [Thomas Freudenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4747/thomas-freudenberg)

This is how it is now:

```
public static Task HideVisibleDialogs(MetroWindow parent)
{
    return Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        await parent.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
        {
            BaseMetroDialog dialogBeingShow = await parent.GetCurrentDialogAsync<BaseMetroDialog>();

            while (dialogBeingShow != null)
            {
                await parent.HideMetroDialogAsync(dialogBeingShow);
                dialogBeingShow = await parent.GetCurrentDialogAsync<BaseMetroDialog>();
            }
        });
    });      
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
HideVisibleDialogs(parent).Wait();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HideVisibleDialogs` is an async method. I'd try to change its return type to `Task` and wait for it, i.e. `HideVisibleDialogs(parent).Wait()`. Otherwise the call would immediately return.

Comment: I thought about using Tasks, the problem is that HideVisibleDialogs must run on the same thread as UI (otherwise it will throw an exception saying that the calling thread cannot access the object because a different thread owns it). Is there a way of forcing a task to run on a specific thread? Here's how my method looks like now: http://pastebin.com/raw/rxKE2frU (I'll edit the question an put it on it if I solve it this way). Thank you for your time!

Comment: Try calling `HideVisibleDialogs` through the dispatcher: `parent.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<Task>(() => HideVisibleDialogs(parent)));` (Haven't tried myself, as I don't have a repro)