# MahApp MessageDialog Hide

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using two thread, one will ask user Question with **[MahApps MessageDialog](http://mahapps.com/controls/dialogs.html)** in `WPF`,

Another I want to Hide the MessageDialog, How to Hide the MessageDialog in `HideMessageDialog()` in the code below?

I'm doing something that need to interrupt the question, and keep the main window open simultaneously. So I need a way to hide the dialog after dialog really show.

```
    public void Execute()
    {
        Task showAsk = new Task(ShowAskingDialog);
        Task hideAsk = new Task(HideAskingByCode);

        showAsk.Start();
        hideAsk.Start();
    }

    public async void ShowAskingDialog()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        this.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme = MetroDialogColorScheme.Accented;
        var msgbox_settings = new MetroDialogSettings { 
        AffirmativeButtonText = "I know", NegativeButtonText = "I don't know" };

        // puase at asking MessaageDialog
        var isKnow = await this.ShowMessageAsync(
                    "Question", "Do you know WPF?", 
                    MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative, msgbox_settings);

    }

    public void HideAskingByCode()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        //How to Hide the MessageDialog by code, not by user click Button?
        HideMessageDialog();
    }
```

The MessageDialog will show like this, embedded in Main Window:

[image]

Comment: Better than hiding it pass a bool parameter in `Execute(bool hide)`, then according to the argument passed, invoke `Task showAsk = new Task(ShowAskingDialog);
showAsk.Start();`

Comment: Thanks, what I want to do is after dialog really show, how to hide it, because I'm doing with something need to Interrupt the question, and have to keep the main window open at the same time.  I'll add this detial into quesiton.

Comment: Ok, if that is so [this might come in handy for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789431/hide-all-visible-metro-dialogs-before-showing-another-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Nobody and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789431/hide-all-visible-metro-dialogs-before-showing-another-one),

Hide the MessageDialog can use general `HideMetroDialogAsync()`:

```
public void HideMessageDialog ()
{    
     this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        async () =>{

            BaseMetroDialog dialogBeingShow = 
                await this.GetCurrentDialogAsync<BaseMetroDialog>();

            //Hide Current Single Dialog
            if(dialogBeingShow != null)
                await this.HideMetroDialogAsync(dialogBeingShow);

            //Or Hide All Dialogs
            while (dialogBeingShow != null)
            {
               await this.HideMetroDialogAsync(dialogBeingShow);
               dialogBeingShow = 
                   await this.GetCurrentDialogAsync<BaseMetroDialog>();
            }

                }
             );
}
```